# error al guardar en un vector los valores de un Select

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar en un vector los valores de un Select, pero aparece el error  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, pon el código (y el stacktrace) como texto, de forma que pueda ayudar a búsquedas de futuros usuarios. Revisa [help], [ask] y [faq].

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes un vector (usuarios) vacío. Lo instancias en la línea 131 pero no tiene nada dentro. Cuando intentas acceder a cualquier posición te va a dar null porque el tamaño del vector es 0. Mejor haz algo así en el while:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario();
u.setCodigo(...);
...

usuarios.add(i, u);

i++;
```

De este modo primero creas el usuario y luego lo añades al vector.